# How to create a sysfs attribute_group under an existing sysfs directory?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

So I have sysfs structure /sys/class/drm/device/foo/moo. *moo* is a subdirectory that has been created using an attribute_group.

Now I want to add a subdirectory under *moo* - /sys/class/drm/device/foo/moo/boo. How do I go about creating *boo*?

The attribute creation for *boo* is in a separate file from where *moo* has been created.

- moo.c -> creates attribute_group *moo*
- boo.c -> creates attribute_group *boo* that must be added under *moo*

How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In general you should **not** do this. In practice it can be done with manipulation kobjects. Each sysfs object is representation of the respective kobject.